# Performance of rendering SVG images on HTML 5 canvas

Tags: svg, html5-canvas

SVG images are great for high detailed graphics, but since they consist of a number of coordinates that need to be calculated before rendering, are they potentially bad for performance, say compared to rendering a jpg which is simply drawing an array of pre-calculated pixels?

I use Context.drawImage, and I do not know if the SVG graphics need to be calculated every drawn frame of the canvas or if they are perhaps cached somehow? or maybe I'm worrying about nothing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The performance will depend on your specific application and the complexity of your graphic, but generally speaking the vector graphics are not going to have a significant impact.  Your main bottleneck will typically be in manipulating the pixel data in the canvas; the larger your canvas, the more time it will take to draw.

Unless you are redrawing the canvas every frame however, the only calculations that are performed at all are those made when you initially draw the image.  When you are not modifying it, the canvas is effectively nothing more than a static bitmap.

Comment: Hi Krash, thanks for the answer. To clarify, I am animating objects on my canvas, so I am actually re-drawing the SVG every frame. I suppose its the same for none SVG images in that I should be caching them in a separate none visible canvas?

Comment: If you're drawing it more than once, yes, buffering your SVG to an offscreen canvas will be quicker (make sure to just buffer it when initially loading it of course, and not every frame).  The canvas context will process and rasterize the image into a canvas bitmap, allowing the pixel data to be added to your destination canvas directly without any additional preamble.